# Javascript onload with master page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need a javascript function to fire when my aspx page has loaded. The problem is it's in a master page. If I put the code in the onload of the master page then it tries to fire for every page that uses the master page. I only want it to happen for one specific page. If I put it in the Content placeholder it doesn't work. The control isn't loaded yet. I tried putting it at the bottom of the content placeholder and that didn't work either. So I need it to happen in an onLoad event but one that only fires for this specific page and not every page that uses the master page.

Please, no jQuery.

Comment: can you do `window.onload = function()` in your ContentArea at the top?

Comment: Didn't work. I ended up going with style="%Response.Write(hdnField.Value);%>" and injecting display:block or display:none directly into the markup.

Comment: why won't you make another layout? and assign it to a specific page. lets say you copy the master page and name it master2 then you assign it to that page. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I have got from you question that you have some javascript function in your master page, that you want to call from a specific aspx page.

Suppose you have a javascript function `hello` in your master page. as :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hello(name) {
        alert('hello '+ name);
    }
</script>
```

this you can call in the page load event of any aspx page using `Page.RegisterStartupScript` as :

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript("hi", "<script>hello('Sanjeev')</script>");
```

So will be able to call master page's javascript function form your aspx page code behind.